Trying to pass prompt value into the code in Azure DevOps (python)
I am trying to get userStory value from user while running build pipeline in Azure DevOps. I want to use that value as a variable into the python script that I am building. I tried below code with yaml, Also attached is the error.
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
  - name: UserStory
    displayName: Enter User Story ID.
    type: string
    default: ''

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.x'
    addToPath: true
  
- script: |
    echo "Running p1.py with User Story ID ${UserStory}"
    export USER_STORY_ID=${UserStory}
    python p1.py
  displayName: 'Run p1.py'

p1.py
import os

print('Hello, world!')
user_story2 = os.getenv('USER_STORY_ID')
print(user_story2)

Error:
    ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/e91b2e42-ada0-4108-aa1f-8bb3b4b6d4a3.sh
Running p1.py with User Story ID 
Hello, world!


Doesn't $(..) execute the stuff inbetween the ( )?  Don't you use { and } instead?  i.e.  ${Userstory}

It seems like the issue is with accessing the UserStory parameter within the Python script. Double-check the variable name and ensure it's being set correctly in the build pipeline

Changed the brackets, error got resolved but still no value getting printed

Hi @Salman, have you tried to read parameter via ${{parameters.name}}? Did it work for you?

If any of the below answers helped you please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

The right syntax to use a parameter is ${{ parameters.xxx }}:
- script: |
    echo "Running p1.py with User Story ID ${{ parameters.UserStory }}"
    export USER_STORY_ID=${{ parameters.UserStory }}
    python p1.py
  displayName: 'Run p1.py'

Also, you don't need to set the environment variable in the script body using the export command.
Set an environment variable at the task level instead:
- script: |
    echo "Running p1.py with User Story ID ${{ parameters.UserStory }}"
    python p1.py
  displayName: 'Run p1.py'
  env:
   USER_STORY_ID: ${{ parameters.UserStory }}


As mentioned by @Rui Jarimba and in this question, the syntax to read parameters is ${{parameters.name}}. See the details from Runtime parameters.
Updated YAML:
- script: |
    echo "Running p1.py with User Story ID ${{parameters.UserStory}}"
    export USER_STORY_ID=${{parameters.UserStory}}
    python p1.py
  displayName: 'Run p1.py'

Result:


Answer Salman's question as he asked here.
